# Find duplicate in Talend

Tags: talend

I have a flow of data like this:

```
2014-03-04
2014-03-04
2014-03-04
2014-03-04
2014-03-04
2014-03-04
2014-03-04
2014-03-04
2014-03-05
2014-03-05
2014-03-05
2014-03-05
2014-03-05
2014-03-05
2014-03-05
2014-03-05
```

Now when I am trying to find duplicate from this 16 rows I can't find any duplicates.

I am using tuniqrow. It is having only one column Start_Time.The Dates are declared as String.

After tuniqrow I can see ll this 16dates are passing to tlogrow whereas only 2 should pass.

Comment: hello, can you format properly next time please it's really difficult to undertans. thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to :

- Put a "unique link" at the output of tuniqrow.
- Tick the case "key attribute" on the column you want to be unique.

like :

[image]